# Return error message when duplicate unique fields

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I want to return error message when duplicate records occur, groupName  is unique field in group table.

I make like this, how can I make error handleing whithout using [mysql-get-diagnostics](http://marcalff.blogspot.com/2011/10/mysql-get-diagnostics.html) because the server I am working on is version 5.0.77-log.

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE addNewGroup(IN groupName varchar(128), IN addedBy INT,OUT message varchar(128) )

 BEGIN


   insert IGNORE  into  `group`( `group_name`,`Date_time_ added`,`added_by`) values (groupName ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),addedBy) ;


END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to return error message when duplication occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method -

```
BEGIN
  INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES...;
  IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
    SET message = 'duplicate records occur';
  END IF;
END
```

[ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function returns the number of inserted rows for the last statement.

In MySQL 5.5. you can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal-resignal.html) statement to generate a warning.